# jQuery set data to slide with ajax auto refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery slide text. It working OK.

But now I want the content of slide text get from database using jQuery Ajax auto refresh.

```
<div id="slides">
    <p class="quote-phrase"></p>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
setInterval(function()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "chk",
        type: "POST",
        data:
        {
        },
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (jsonStr)
        {
            $('.quote-phrase').empty();
            var slideLen = jsonStr.slide.length;
            for(var i=0; i<slideLen; i++)
            {
                var slide = jsonStr.slide[i];

                var newOption2 = $('<span>'+slide+'</span>');
                $('.quote-phrase').append(newOption2);
            }
        }
    }
}, 1000);
```

When I put this `$('.quote-phrase').append(newOption2);` it only show always 1 data (I have more data there and checked json result there are more data).

Here is the jsonStr result:

> {"islamicDate":"11 Shafar 1439","logo":"logo.jpg","mosqueName":"MT. Nurullah","mosqueAddress":"Jalan Gaharu Lot 218, Muka Kuning","mosqueWebsite":"http://mtnurullah.com","mosqueTelp":"0770-611711","latitude":"103.92000000","longitude":"1.03000000","altitude":"3.07","timezone":"+7","calculationMethod":"Depag","currentTime":"17:52:02","message":["Diharapkan kepada seluruh jamaah agar meluruskan dan merapatkan shaf ketika sholat","Test 2","Test 3"],"slide":["Dari Anas bin Malik r.a. berkata: Rasulullah saw bersabda, \"Sesungguhnya Allah lebih suka menerima taubat seorang hamba-Nya melebihi kesenangan seorang yang menemukan kembali tiba-tiba untanya yang telah hilang daripadanya di tengah hutan\". (Bukhari -\r\n Muslim)","Dari Abu Said dan Abu Hurairah r.a. berkata: Rasulullah saw bersabda, \"Tiadalah seorang Muslim itu menderita kelelahan atau penyakit atau kesusahan (kerisauan hati) hingga tertusuk duri melainkan semua itu akan menjadi penebus kesalahan-kesalahannya.\""]}

Comment: share your jsonStr data or some dummy data in same format so that we can help you

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 2):

```js
var jsonstr = {"islamicDate":"11 Shafar 1439", "logo":"logo.jpg", "mosqueName":"MT. Nurullah", "mosqueAddress":"Jalan Gaharu Lot 218, Muka Kuning", "mosqueWebsite":"http:\/\/mtnurullah.com", "mosqueTelp":"0770-611711", "latitude":"103.92000000", "longitude":"1.03000000", "altitude":"3.07", "timezone":"+7", "calculationMethod":"Depag", "currentTime":"17:52:02", "message":["Diharapkan kepada seluruh jamaah agar meluruskan dan merapatkan shaf ketika sholat", "Test 2", "Test 3"], "slide":["Dari Anas bin Malik r.a. berkata: Rasulullah saw bersabda, \"Sesungguhnya Allah lebih suka menerima taubat seorang hamba-Nya melebihi kesenangan seorang yang menemukan kembali tiba-tiba untanya yang telah hilang daripadanya di tengah hutan\". (Bukhari -\r\n Muslim)", "Dari Abu Said dan Abu Hurairah r.a. berkata: Rasulullah saw bersabda, \"Tiadalah seorang Muslim itu menderita kelelahan atau penyakit atau kesusahan (kerisauan hati) hingga tertusuk duri melainkan semua itu akan menjadi penebus kesalahan-kesalahannya.\""]};
                    $('.quote-phrase').empty();
                    $.each(jsonstr,function( index,element){
                        if (typeof element == Array){
                            element.forEach(function(element1, index){
                                var newOption2 = $('<span>' + element1 + '</span></br></br>');
                                $('.quote-phrase').append(newOption2);
                            });
                            
                        }else{
                            var newOption2 = $('<span>' + element + '</span></br></br>');
                            $('.quote-phrase').append(newOption2);
                        }
                        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quote-phrase"></div>
```

Comment: Hi.. What I want is each data will slide. Not directly that 2 data slide

Answer (score 1):

Code is working fine. I have created a demo which works. you are appending a `<span>` to `<p>` tag and it shows the output in continious format which might cause you to think it as a single entity. i have added `</br>` to know the difference.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var jsonStr = {"islamicDate":"11 Shafar 1439","logo":"logo.jpg","mosqueName":"MT. Nurullah","mosqueAddress":"Jalan Gaharu Lot 218, Muka Kuning","mosqueWebsite":"http:\/\/mtnurullah.com","mosqueTelp":"0770-611711","latitude":"103.92000000","longitude":"1.03000000","altitude":"3.07","timezone":"+7","calculationMethod":"Depag","currentTime":"17:52:02","message":["Diharapkan kepada seluruh jamaah agar meluruskan dan merapatkan shaf ketika sholat","Test 2","Test 3"],"slide":["Dari Anas bin Malik r.a. berkata: Rasulullah saw bersabda, \"Sesungguhnya Allah lebih suka menerima taubat seorang hamba-Nya melebihi kesenangan seorang yang menemukan kembali tiba-tiba untanya yang telah hilang daripadanya di tengah hutan\". (Bukhari -\r\n Muslim)","Dari Abu Said dan Abu Hurairah r.a. berkata: Rasulullah saw bersabda, \"Tiadalah seorang Muslim itu menderita kelelahan atau penyakit atau kesusahan (kerisauan hati) hingga tertusuk duri melainkan semua itu akan menjadi penebus kesalahan-kesalahannya.\""]};

    $('.quote-phrase').empty();
            var slideLen = jsonStr.slide.length;
            for(var i=0; i<slideLen; i++)
            {
                var slide = jsonStr.slide[i];

                var newOption2 = $('<span>'+slide+'</span></br></br>');
                $('.quote-phrase').append(newOption2);
            }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slides">
    <p class="quote-phrase"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi... I tried the code. It show me like the demo you give. What I want It should be slide of each.

Comment: For that post your sliding code which is working without dynamic data

Answer (score 0):

You remove all elements from the slider every second, and then repopulate it. Which means the slider can't get to the 2nd element this way.

To solve this, you have to check which elements to add/remove instead of just clearing it all.

If you replace the code inside the `success` by this, it should work:

```
//Check if we need to remove elements first.
$(".quote-phrase span").each(function() {

    //If we can't find it: remove it.
    var index = jsonStr.slide.indexOf($(this).text());
    if (index == -1)
        $(this).remove();
    else
        jsonStr.slide.splice(index, 1);
})

//Check if we need to add items:
for (var i = 0; i < jsonStr.slide.length; i++) {

    var slide = jsonStr.slide[i];
    var newOption2 = $('<span>'+slide+'</span>');
    $('.quote-phrase').append(newOption2);
}
```